# Where are my roundcube logs stored?

Tags: roundcube

In my roundcube config file `config.inc.php` I have found

`// LOGGING
$config['log_driver'] = 'syslog'; 
$config['syslog_facility'] = LOG_MAIL;`

but I still don't know where I can find these logs.

I'm looking for logs because when I try logging into any mail account on my roundcube I get the message `error connecting with server`

Can anyone tell me where these logs are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This logs are in `/var/log/maillog/`

Comment: In my case it was `/var/log/dovecot.log`

Answer (score 0):

On my Fedora Server v 35 it's `/var/log/roundcubemail`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have changed `phi.ini` file records as follows

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
```

but it was not showing an effect on RoundCube webmail.

I just checked the PHP error logs:

```
/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini
```

I got an error in line 679 or something.

> Database support - SQLite (pdo_sqlite) extension not found; variables are not used within a script, having this directive on will result

When I checked, the below line was not commented in `php.ini` file. I just placed a `;` before the line, saved the file, and restarted the Apache2 server. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation settings where wrong. In file roundcube/config/config.inc.php
//$config['smtp_server'] = 'localhost';//

//$config['smtp_server'] = '%t';//

and works again.

Comment: as well I had //$config['default_host'] = 'localhost'; // changed to //$config['default_host'] = '%t';//